# Time complexity of this simple code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

In pseudo-code:

```
j = 5;

while (j <= n) {

    j = j* j* j * j;
}
```

What is the time complexity of this code?
It is way shorter than O(logn), is there even any reason to go lower than that?

Comment: `O(1)` is lower...

Comment: Of course, but this can't be considered as O(1), can it?

Comment: of course not...

Comment: My thoughts were this:
It might never stop because of overflow issues, where n will be just bigger than the biggest number j arrives and then becomes negative. But, it does not always repeat the same numbers, so eventually, we will reach the right number to make the while halt, but how can this be measured by n?

Comment: Will never execute because n is undefined. complexity is zero.

Comment: @code_mode For Big-O notation we assume that the relevant calculations are carried out mathematically correct, using a sufficiently large (or unlimited) datatype. If you're interested in a specific bit-limited, signed integer type, mention the appropriate "modulo" expression in your pseudo-code (32-bit integer doesn't even suffice for the second iteration), and then Big-O won't give you a plausible run-time prediction model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's trace through the execution of the code. Suppose we start with initial value `j0`:

```
0. j ← j0
1. j ← j0^4
2. j ← [j0^4]^4 = j0^(4^2)
3. j ← [j0^(4^2)]^4 = j0^(4^3)
4. j ← [j0^(4^3)]^4 = j0^(4^4)
...
m. j ← [j0^(4^(m-1))]^4 = j0^(4^m)
```

... after `m` loops.

The loop terminates when the value exceeds `n`:

```
j0^(4^m) > n
→m > log(4, log(j0, n))
```

Thus the time complexity is `O(m) = O(log log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I used [help from MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2425471/286229) to find out how to solve this. The answer is same as another one by @meowgoesthedog, but I understand it the following way:

On every iteration, the value of j is going to increase by its own 4<sup>th</sup> power. Or, we can look at it from the side of *n*, that on every iteration *n* is going to reduce by its 4<sup>th</sup> root. Hence, the recurrence will look like:

> T(n) = 1 + T(n<sup>1/4</sup>)

For any integer *k*, with 2<sup>4<sup>k</sup></sup> + 1 <= n <= 2<sup>4<sup>k + 1</sup></sup>, the recurrence will become:

> T(n) = 1 + k

if we go on to assume that the 4<sup>th</sup> root will always be an integer. It won't matter if it is not as the constant of +/- 1 will be ignored in the Big-O calculation.

Now, since the assumption of 4<sup>th</sup> root being an integer simplifies things for us, we can try to solve the following equation:

n = 2<sup>4<sup>k</sup></sup>,

with the equation yielding k = (Log(Log(n)) - Log(2))/Log(4).

This implies that O(T(n)) = O(Log(Log(n))).

Comment: Why is the base equal to 2? I thought it should be 5 in this case (or the initial value of `j`); but I guess it doesn't matter in the asymptotic sense

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I started with base 2 because it keeps the calculations simple when solving the recurrence. Looking from _n_'s side, the recurrence is not going to change with the value of _j_. However, even if we take the base as 5 (or j), the constants (i.e. Log(5)) will be neglected anyway.